# How to match every word in the list having single sentence using python

Tags: python

how to match the below case 1 in python.. i want each and every word in the sentence to be matched with the list.

```
l1=['there is a list of contents available in the fields']
>>> 'there' in l1
False
>>> 'there is a list of contents available in the fields' in l1
True
```

Comment: Your list only contains one element, what it the point of not having just a string there? Anyway, `'there' in l1[0]` should return True.

Comment: im performing web scraping .. required a similar methodology..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way

```
l1=['there is a list of contents available in the fields']
>>> 'there' in l1[0]
True
```

Better way wil be to iterate to all element of list.

```
l1=['there is a list of contents available in the fields']
print(bool([i for i in l1 if 'there' in i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if any of the string in the list contains a word no matter which string it is you can do this:

```
if any('there' in element for element in li):
    pass
```

Now if you want to filter the ones which matches the string you can simply:

```
li = filter(lambda x: 'there' in x, li)
```

Or in Python 3:

```
li = list(filter(lambda x: 'there' in x, li))
```